# RecyclerView won't display my database content

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a database of Users and I'm trying to use a RecyclerView to display every User entry I have. From my logs, I can tell that my RecyclerView isn't even being interacted with. Here is the class where I call it:

```
public class WelcomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_page);

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    RecyclerFragment mRecyclerFragment = new RecyclerFragment();
    if(mRecyclerFragment == null) {
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.recycler, mRecyclerFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
}
```

This is my holder class:

```
public class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

private static final String TAG = "RecyclerHolder";

private TextView mFullName;
private TextView mBirthDate;
private TextView mHomeTown;
private TextView mBio;
User mUser;

RecyclerHolder(View itemView){
    super(itemView);

    mFullName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
    mBirthDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_birthday);
    mHomeTown = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_hometown);
    mBio = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_bio);

public void bind(User user) {
    mUser = user;
    mFullName.setText(user.getFullName());
    mBirthDate.setText(user.getBirthDate().toString());
    mHomeTown.setText(user.getHomeTown());
    mBio.setText(user.getBio());
}

}
```

Here's my adapter class:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerHolder> {
private ArrayList<User> mUsers;

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<User> user) {
    mUsers = user;
}

@Override
public RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_recycler, parent, false);
    RecyclerHolder holder = new RecyclerHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerHolder holder, int position){
    holder.bind(mUsers.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUsers.size();
}

}
```

Here's my fragment class:

```
public class RecyclerFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
DBCursorWrapper db;

public RecyclerFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(db.getUserList());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;

}

}
```

Here is the XML for my holder:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/view_recycler">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my XML for my fragment:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/recycler"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.csc214.just4kas.project02.RecyclerFragment">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Here is my XML for where I call my RecyclerView:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frame_layout_recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.csc214.just4kas.project02.WelcomePage">

</FrameLayout>
```

The getUserList() has been tested individually and works perfectly!

Any help would be super appreciated! I just want a RecyclerView of all the contents in my database!! Thanks!

Comment: can you debug and check if getUserList is returning the value?

Comment: @AjayShrestha it's not returning a value.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: paste the code for UserCursorWrapper too

Comment: @AjayShrestha edited to include!

Comment: dont check for count, check for moveToFirst and try

Comment: @AjayShrestha it still doesn't work. With my log tags, I've determined that the fragment is, at the very least, getting inflated. After that, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you separately call and check the return value of db.getUserList()

Comment: @AjayShrestha just tested! My getUseList() works!! The issue, then, must be coming from somewhere else. I think my RecyclerView is never being accessed somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be using the wrong layout when you replace add it to the main activity. try (R.id.frame_layout_recycler_view) instead or R.id.recycler.

Or there might be a issue when use the database in this context.